# Fetch json data on Button click in React

Tags: reactjs, json, button, onclick

I want to Display single record from json file

App.js

```
const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

return (

<tbody> 
{currentTableData.map(item => {
   
 <div>
      <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>{visible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</button>
      {visible && <div>{item.title}</div>}
    </div>

</tbody>
)
```

data.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "AAA"  
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "BBB"  
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "CCC"  
  }

]
```

I want to show single data( title here)  while clicking particular button, instead of showing all titles on single click

Answer (score 0):

set IDs on click into useState and use

```js
const currentTableData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "AAA"  
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "BBB"  
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "CCC"  
  }

];

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      {currentTableData.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <button
            onClick={() => setVisible(visible.includes(item.id)
              ? visible.filter(vId => vId !== item.id)
              : [...visible, item.id])}
          >
            {visible.includes(item.id) ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
          </button>
          {visible.includes(item.id) && <div>{item.title}</div>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```